# Finding time ranges which intersect with given time range

Tags: javascript, d3.js, quadtree

Let's suppose we have long list of time ranges:

```
var timeRanges = [...] as Array<[Date, Date]>
```

and time range:

```
var searchTimeRange = [startDate, endDate]
```

We have to find elements from `timeRanges` array that intersect with `searchTimeRange` range.

I was thinking about using d3 quadtree, but it appears it doesn't support rectanges as input. In general I'd like to avoid O(n).

Answer (score 1):

Ok it was simple, I've used: R-Tree.

https://github.com/mourner/rbush

It allows for efficient queries.

Answer (score 0):

```
function processTimes = function(time) {
  return (time > searchTimeRange[0] && time < searchTimeRange[1])
}

var processedTimes = timeRanges(filter(processTimes))
```

Comment: I'd like to avoid O(n)

Comment: it's not possible